# Class data member memory layout shows over-large pointer sizes?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction

This is my class (the data members anyway):

```
class X{

public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Y> > a;
    std::unordered_map<double, long> b;
    std::set<double> c;
    std::map<double, long> d;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, long> e;
    std::string f;
    std::mutex g;
};
```

and this is the layout generated by the MSVC 2012 compiler:

```
1>  class X size(264):
1>      +---
1>   0  |  a
1>  64  |  b
1>  128 |  c
1>  144 |  d
1>  160 |  e
1>  224 |  f
1>  256 |  g
1>      +---
```

I don't understand why the container data members have such large gaps between their offsets? The addresses are in terms of bytes- so my `unordered_map<double, long>` data member has a 64-byte pointer?!

Just thought- obviously there could be padding, but why so much!?

Comment: Please produce a layout in release mode

Comment: Your `std::unordered_map<double, long>` isn't a pointer to an object, it's the actual object.

Comment: @DieterLücking that is release mode...

Comment: @NiallC. I thought std::containers have pointers for the data member, which refer to the heap-allocated data structure?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Many std::containers may *contain* only a pointer, but as sizeof works at compile time, it doesn't know whether the string is empty or not, or the string stream. At compile time, they are. Your result is meaningless, except to the extent it indicates there's probably only a pointer inside.

Comment: Which compiler? The numbers will vary.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN (1) A container type such as std::string isn't a pointer, but it might contain a pointer, and it might contain nothing else. It isn't the same thing. (2) I haven't said a word about 'my' std::string. (3) The question is about why some objects are *larger* than 64 bits. You're just creating confusion with all this irrelevance.

Answer (score 0):

The unordered_map class probably contains several pointers data members for its implementation and probably some size data members. each of these is 8 bytes so you can easily get to 64 bytes in total. same goes for set and map.

Answer (score 0):

There are no pointers in this class. All these things are objects, not pointers. They in turn may contain other objects, pointers, etc. There is no reason to expect any of these members to occupy only 64 bits, without knowing what's inside them.

Comment: Except for boost, all these are in the standard library. You can easily see what's inside them.